# Python Tkinter Label - Updating Based on Dropdown Menus

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a label at the bottom of my Tkinter window that will update, based on the selected dropdowns, when the user hits the "generate" button. I've gotten to the point where I have my code working without error, but it does not output the label, it stays as Py_var0. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong here? I know it has to be in the run function, or the way the Labelvar is being set incorrectly, but I'm relatively new to Python so I'm stuck! I've tried looking it up and my code looks to me like I have it set up like all the examples and answers I found, so I must be missing something obvious!

Thanks for any help:

```
from tkinter import *

kb = Tk()

def run():

    global Labelvar

    if var1.get() == "A":
        Labelvar.set("Label updated")

    resultlabel.config(text=Labelvar)

    return

Labelvar = StringVar(kb)

var1 = StringVar(kb)

var1.set("A")

resultlabel = Label(kb, text=Labelvar)

menu = OptionMenu(kb, var1, "A", "B", "C")

generate = Button(kb, text="Go", command=run)

menu.grid(row=1, column=2)

generate.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

resultlabel.grid(row=5, column=1)

mainloop()
```

Comment: The `text=` option of a Label directly sets its text: setting this this to a Tk variable just uses the auto-generated name of the variable, which isn't likely to be useful.  You want the `textvariable=` option instead, which connects the Label to the variable's value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at `resultlabel.config(text=Labelvar)` as text parameter requires a string, but if you pass something else (not sure though) such as StringVar, the label will grab what you passed and apply `str()` to it. To solve this

```
from tkinter import *

kb = Tk()

def run():

    if var1.get() == "A":
        Labelvar.set("Label updated")

    resultlabel.config(textvariable=Labelvar)

    return

Labelvar = StringVar()

var1 = StringVar()

var1.set("A")

resultlabel = Label(kb, textvariable=Labelvar)

menu = OptionMenu(kb, var1, "A", "B", "C")

generate = Button(kb, text="Go", command=run)

menu.grid(row=1, column=2)

generate.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

resultlabel.grid(row=5, column=1)
#This two methods are simply for testing purposes. It works.
run()
kb.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried resultlabel.config(textvariable=Labelvar) and it still gives the same result, the label does not change, and now does not show text at all

Comment: added more fixes, try now

Comment: Still the same result!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a label at the bottom of my Tkinter window that
> will update, but it does not output the label

The problem can be fixed.

Avoid wildcard `*`. Use `import tkinter as tk`, then `tk.` prefix.

- Use one variable `StringVar()` to pass `Label` widget.
- Comment out `var1` and `var1.set`.
- In `run()` function, comment out `#if var1.get() == "A":` and
  `#Labelvar.set("Label updated")` and `#return`
- In `run()`, add configure and use f-string format.

Snippet modified small code:

```
import tkinter as tk

kb = tk.Tk()

def run():
   resultlabel['text'] = f'You selected: {var1.get()}'


var1 = tk.StringVar()

resultlabel = tk.Label(kb)

menu = tk.OptionMenu(kb, var1, "A", "B", "C")

generate = tk.Button(kb, text="Go", command=run)

menu.grid(row=1, column=2)

generate.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.W)

resultlabel.grid(row=5, column=1)

kb.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]